# How to change the Orientation for fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I have managed to change the Orientation for my fragment in my activity.
The Orientation is changed when my device is rotated.

Now I want to same functionality when I click on a button in the fragment.
i.e. I want to change from portrait mode to LandScape mode when I click on a button on the portrait layout and visa vera.

I used

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

and

```
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

respectively.

But this made the auto rotate functionality stop working. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try it... fix the orientation in android manifest

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Can you please explain me more about this like how do I do this in manifist file... I am new to this...

Answer (score 4):

When you need auto rotating use `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
             <activity 
              android:name="<class name with package>"
                   android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the reply...
But this solution is not working.. 
Having the following issues with the approach you have mentioned...
1. The activity is not switching to landscape mode when I rotate/turn my mobile
2. When I click on the button, which should show the Landscape mode layout..., Its referring to the portrait layout file and showing it in Landscape mode...
So this solution not working... any other solution you have please let me know...

thank you
Raj

Comment: I have only one fragment which have landscape orintation and rest are in portrait... how can I fix this issue and make it working...
I tried the above solution but dint not work.. Raj